# Trigger with Autonomous Transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, transactions

I want to know if declaring `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` means that the rule action starts after event transaction `INSERT on tab` has ended (AKA triggering transaction had a successful `COMMIT`).

I'm using Oracle DB 11.2

Here I have added the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rule1
AFTER INSERT ON tab
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
            ALTER TABLE vert_strukt
            ADD '||:NEW.name||' VARCHAR2(40) ');
    INSERT INTO resulted (name_unique)
    VALUES (:NEW.name);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: While there are numerous questions that I could ask about what you are doing here, the simple answer to the question posed is that AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION has nothing to do with timing. As noted on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) it allows for a separate transaction that can commit or rollback without affecting the outer transaction.

Comment: running DDL in a trigger does not seem like something you really should be doing in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use a Stored procedure to do so. Also, no transaction control statements are allowed in a trigger. **ROLLBACK**, **COMMIT**, and **SAVEPOINT** cannot be used.

Comment: The trigger is working fine. I just asked for clarification for `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`